# The import com.google.android.gms.games.Games cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, reference, android-support-library

I'm currently in the process of adding Google play services libraries to my project and trying to incorporate high score functionality. However I am receiving the error:

`The import com.google.android.gms.games.Games cannot be resolved`

I have successfully referenced the Google play services library in my project, shown by the telltale green tick, however the error remains!

I've tried solutions on all the similar threads I could find, and none have seemed to work! (Though maybe I have missed some?)

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825940/com-google-android-gms-games-gamesclient-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: nope, seen it and tried solutions, mine is different

Comment: Could you add a part of the code containing the `import statement` and an associated `method`?

Comment: Did you check http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html and http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html? Could you hover `import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;`, click on `Fix project setup` and select the correct jar and see if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to update lots of stuff in eclipse, that's how I got it to work... Particularly the library, I needed to update that particularly